# access убрать перенос строки в начале

Tags: sql, access

Имеется таблица mdb access 2003.
В некоторых столбцах текст начинается с переноса строки. Как можно его убрать?

Пробовал запросом:
UPDATE LOT SET DYNAMIC1 = replace(DYNAMIC1, '', '');

Опробованные варианты:

\n

\r

\n\r

\r\n

'

'

chr(10) - ругается на неопределённую функцию.

Просто функция replace отрабатывает и текст заменяет.

Comment: Проверил у себя - `Replace([ColumnName],Chr(10),"")` работает без проблем. Chr должно отрабатывать, если нет, то смотрите что с референсами библиотек

Comment: @SergeyS. в 2003 именно?

Comment: Нет, в 2010 пробовал

Comment: @SergeyS. там очень разный набор функций по версиям. Попробовал создать в 16 базу и туда перенести данные после чего заменить переносы - всё хорошо. А вот если использовать mdb 2003 access то он просто ругается на функцию chr.

Answer (score 0):

$replacelogin = $login;
$login = substr($replacelogin, '1');